# MKMap infinite loop setting max zoom height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a map view with an overlay. I want to restrict the user from zooming out too far. So if the user scrolls out and cant see part of the overlay it zooms them back in to the max height of the overlay. Like the zooming I also want the user not to be able to scroll of the edge.

I have managed to implement this (or so I thought). The code that I have written works on my iPhone 5 but then when I tested it on my Bosses phone and the simulator the map keeps trying to resize and get stuck in an infinite loop.

Here is a video of my app in the [Loop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwuikg4Jjrw).

From the video I can see that the map should loop as both edges are displayed off the map. To stop this my code zooms in so you cant see both edges before it is meant to move back to the edge the user has moved from.

As I said this works on one of my device but not the others! I have been trying to fix this for three days now and feel like banging my head on the keyboard! Any help would be amazing.

Here is a copy of my [Code](http://pastebin.com/q5UcQMcN). 
I have commented it and tried to make it easy to under stand.

EDIT: just updated to iOS 6.0.1. It still works on my iPhone 5 but It starts really far zoomed in and sets the min zoom too low